# Stylus: why does stdin produce a different result when using require?

Tags: node.js, npm, stylus, package.json

I'm trying to use `npm` as my `task manager` and I noticed something weird with the `Stylus CLI` that I don't under stand.

To run `Stylus CLI` on a file, I have two options.
`$ stylus styles/file.styl // basic`
`$ stylus < styles/file.styl // using stdin`

And in file.styl, I'm using `@require` to include some other folders with the wildcard to grab all the files inside the folder.

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@require 'base/*';
@require 'modules/*';
@require 'theme/*';
```

So, when I run `$ stylus styles/file.styl` it all runs correctly, but if I run `$ stylus < styles/file.styl` I get an error.

I was able to make it work by changing the `@require` calls in my styl file like so:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@require 'styles/base/*';
@require 'styles/modules/*';
@require 'styles/theme/*';
```

But I have no idea why that works and how I can fix it so I can run it via the command line.

The goal is to get it working correctly in the CLI so that I can then use it in my `package.json` and pipe it into other tasks like `autoprefixer` and `combine-mq` or `css-pleeease`. I'm trying to replicate a `gulpfile.js` that I used on the same project, hoping that would allow me to wrap my head around the whole process.

Thanks

UPDATE:
I should also include the `package.json` as a reference to see where I ended up. This also sets up an answer I'm going to post.

```
{
  "name": "npm_BUILD",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "npm as a task manager",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "styles":"npm run styles:max && npm run styles:min",
    "styles:max": "stylus < styles/site.styl | autoprefixer -b 'last 2 versions' > styles/final.css",
    "styles:min": "cssmin < styles/final.css > styles/final.min.css"
  },
  "author": "Jason Lydon @bushwa",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^5.1.1",
    "clean-css": "^3.2.2",
    "combine-mq": "^0.8.1",
    "concat": "^1.0.0",
    "cssmin": "^0.4.3",
    "filesize": "^3.1.2",
    "stylus": "^0.50.0"
  }
}
```

and then I run `$ npm run styles` which creates two css files, the second one is minified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best answer, but this worked for me...

So, building off of Peter Lyon's answer, I updated my command in the `package.json` to jump into the styles directory first and then run!

`stylus < styles/site.styl | autoprefixer -b 'last 2 versions' > styles/final.css`
became
`cd styles && stylus < site.styl | autoprefixer -b 'last 2 versions' > final.css`

```
{
  "name": "npm_BUILD",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "npm as a task manager",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "styles":"npm run styles:max && npm run styles:min",
    "styles:max": "cd styles && stylus < site.styl | autoprefixer -b 'last 2 versions' > final.css",
    "styles:min": "cssmin < styles/final.css > styles/final.min.css"
  },
  "author": "Jason Lydon @bushwa",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^5.1.1",
    "clean-css": "^3.2.2",
    "combine-mq": "^0.8.1",
    "concat": "^1.0.0",
    "cssmin": "^0.4.3",
    "filesize": "^3.1.2",
    "stylus": "^0.50.0"
  }
}
```

I'm not going to lie, this made me nerd happy.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with whether or not stylus knows the filesystem path of the top-level input file. When you pass it the path to `styles/file.styl` it interprets the `require` calls as relative to that `styles/file.styl` file and all is well. When you pipe to stdin, stylus only knows your current working directory in the shell, so it interprets relative paths relative to that, which in your case is the parent directory of `styles`. If you were to `cd styles` then it would probably work both ways.

My suggestion is to use paths relative to the top-level .styl file as that is pretty sane, just make sure you `cd` into that directory before running `stylus`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It actually led me to try something crazy that worked. See my answer for more info...